# How to programmatically set UISlider initial value, or, how does an iOS program start up?

Tags: ios, xcode, startup, uislider

I have been developing in xCode for exactly 3 days now.  The last time I did UI development it was in Windows 3.1 with the Petzold book.  Regardless of that I have my first iOS app up and running and it basically does what I need.  I have two sliders to select hue and saturation, and in response to them I dynamically draw a bunch of gradient shaded circles.  I got that much running between the Hello World example and stackoverflow, including caching the gradient in CGLayer (so thanks to all the stackoverflow people).  There is one little piece that I can't quite get right though:

I want to set the initial value of one slider to 1.0 instead of the default 0.5.  I know I can do that in IB, but I prefer to code it and I think I'd like to move away from IB altogether.  I don't really understand how it makes connections between things and I'd like to understand the code.  I have code like this to try to set it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [hue_slider setValue:0.5];
    [sat_slider setValue:1.0];
    self.led_view.hue_slider_value=0.5;
    self.led_view.sat_slider_value=1.0;
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

sat_slider still ends up in the middle instead of at the end (1.0 is the max value).  From stackexchange reading I understand that I am probably calling this at the wrong time, that the slider hasn't really been loaded when viewDidLoad is called, and my initial value is overwritten by the one specified in IB.  What I haven't seen though is where the call should be made.  So the question:

Where in my program should I put

```
[sat_slider setValue:1.0];
```

so that it sets the initial value of the slider, overwriting the default in IB?  Can someone explain the order of how things start up in an iOS program?  And a pointer to online or printed books regarding iOS and Objective C programming would be great.

**Edit**

When I check the value of sat_slider it is nil. So that means a connection is missing? I dragged it in the storyboard and created an IBOutlet in addition to an action.

```
@interface led_testViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)saturation_scroll:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)hue_scroll:(id)sender;

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *hue_slider;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *sat_slider;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet led_view *led_view;

@end
```

Comment: Can you check if 'sat_slider' is not nil while setting the value? Is it properly connected via IB?

Comment: Toss this in your `viewDidLoad` method: `NSLog(@"sat_slider is:%@",self.sat_slider);`

Comment: Kind of off topic but loading views and other objects from nibs is interesting to learn about how it works and you'll understand how it sets the connections - it's not magic despite some claims to the contrary :)

Comment: @ABC: you are right, when I check the value of sat_slider it is nil.  So that means a connection is missing?  I dragged it in the storyboard and created an IBOutlet in addition to an action:

`
@interface led_testViewController : UIViewController
- (IBAction)saturation_scroll:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)hue_scroll:(id)sender;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *hue_slider;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *sat_slider;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet led_view *led_view;
`

Comment: ABC and NJones: you are right, when I check the value of sat_slider it is nil.  I had IBOutlet properties for both sliders but something must have been missing.  I deleted both properties from the .h file and re-dragged them in the storyboard and now I can set the values just fine in viewDidLoad.  That's kind of what I'm getting at with wanting to move away from IB.  Lots to learn...  Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: You really did not need to completely remove the property, you just had to reconnect it. You can very easily check if a property is correctly connected in IB by bringing up the view controller's .h file in assistant editor, then performing a mouse-over/hover on the little circle next to the line number of the property. The connected view will glow. If it's not connected(the circle will be empty) simply drag from that circle to the view to be connected.

Comment: @SteveRavet, I will add that as an answer since that helped you. Please accept.

Answer (score 0):

You may put the code in `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;`

Comment: This is a bad practice because `viewWillAppear:` gets called whenever e.g. the user switches to another tab and comes back. If setting the slider value didn't work in `viewDidLoad` there's a more fundamental problem (as there was in this case) that should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the suggestions of ABC and NJones to check sat_slider and it was nil.  There were properties for both sat_slider and hue_slider in the ViewController.h file, but something was still missing.  I deleted the properties, re-dragged them in IB, and then I was able to set the slider position in viewDidLoad with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `sat_slider` nil. Also make sure that it is properly connected in IB. If not, remove it and add it again in nib/storyboard. That should fix the issue.